# Send Email attachment to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, outlook

I need to upload the attachment which is received outlook email to amazon s3 bucket.

- The email with attachment is received once per day
- Is there any process which can automate this process of uploading it to specific s3 bucket?

I have tried to search for any available add-ins in outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some workflow managers like airtable or automate io. Here is sample integration https://automate.io/integration/amazon-s3/microsoft-outlook

Comment: I have already gone through this. We are not supposed to use third party applications for such tasks

Comment: Add ons are also third party apps

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a VBA macro or COM add-in for handling incoming emails and doing whatever required with them, for example, uploading to any web server (or S3 bucket).

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Use the Entry ID to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

After retrieving the item instance arrived to your Inbox we may save attached files and upload to the web server. The [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) saves the attachment to the specified path.